# How to break out from beginner stage in learning C++

Tags: c++, c

Before I enter the stage of my university's life, I grab a book and start learn about C++ (reading and writing and of course , experimenting with it), I manage to cope myself with the computer programming subject I took during the first semester of my uni's life (I'm taking IT).

I even wrote a program called [Cellular Automata Conway's Game of Life](http://www.mediafire.com/?cotc1cd0k9uokc5), which is a title given by my lecturer to me.

#### The Question:

1. The Question I always have in mind is that how can I really start doing some real world project ? I feel I can grasp the syntax , rules and logics of the language but I can't really make good use of it . I feel there are many things that cannot be accomplished using C++ standard library .
2. If I really wanted to break out from this, do I need to start downloading SDK, framework or API and start making use of it to create software? Or a programmer can just create a full-fledge software out of the standard library of C++?
3. I have an idea of creating browser using C++ , the thing is that I can't even find a way on how to do it (how to make it request a webpage and fetch the content back , how to connect flash player to my browser etc), can we achieve all these using standard library or we need some external agent to do so?

Thank you for spending time reading my situation.

Comment: Write code and you will get experienced. Also, spend time in stackoverflow and you'll learn a lot!

Comment: This is a question for http://programmers.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Do some online coding challenges. The old Facebook Engineering Puzzles were great (though I think they're gone); there's also the Facebook Hacker Cup archive and the Google Code Jam archive, as well as a myriad of other such sites. Try to write the best code you can as you solve each problem.

Comment: Post a class from your program and I'll comment on how to improve it.  You know what, post the whole thing.

Comment: Regarding your wish to create a web-browser: Do it in steps... First learn the basics of the language and system you use; Then learn about sockets, clients and servers; Then learn about the protocol; Then simple graphics and UI programming; More advanced UI and graphics programing; Etc.